# Is there a faster way of creating a new vector by comparing 4 other vectors through rows i and i-1, in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, vector, comparison

Imagine you have a dataset of customers with their purchase history.

The data is ordered by customer and by the date of their activity 
   a.k.a. purchase

The goal is to calculate the frequency of their purchasing, but fastly

```
Data <- tibble(Customer = c("Person A", "Person A", "Person A", "Person A", "Person A", "Person A","Person B", "Person C","Person C"),
           First_Activity_Date = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),   # imagine these numbers as dates
           Activity_Date = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,1,2),         
           Last_Activity_Date =c(6,6,6,6,6,6,1,2,2)
           )

View(Data)

tic()
h <- vector( "integer", length = 9)
f <- function(x, y, z, q){
     for( i in 1:length(x)){
         if ( identical(z[i],y[i])) { h[i] <- 1 }
         else if ( identical(x[i],x[i-1]) && (z[i]<=q[i])) { h[i] <- (h[i-1]+1) }
       }
     return(h)
     }

Data <- mutate(Data, Frequency = f(Customer, First_Activity_Date, 
Activity_Date, Last_Activity_Date) )

View(Data)
toc()



#Data <- select( Data, Customer, First_Activity_Date, Activity_Date, Last_Activity_Date) 
#remove(h)
#remove(f)
```

It works fine with a small dataset filled with numbers, but with a row number over 50K filled with dates it needs about 2 minutes..

Is there a way to vectorize this function/calculation?

Comment: I find it very hard to understand what you want the code to do. Can you add sample data and desired output?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I gave a short explanation above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's build up an alternative solution

```
f1 <- function(x, y, z, q) {
```

Allocate the result vector inside the function, using arguments passed to the function

```
    h <- integer(length(x)) # allocate the result inside the function
```

Your loop consists of parts that can be 'vectorized' (one function call, rather than a function call for each iteration of the loop). Write the vectorized versions

```
    tst_1 <- z == y        # 'hoist' outside loop as vectorized comparison
    h[tst_1] <- 1L         # update h; '1L': integer, not '1': numeric
```

The `else` part of the conditional has a bug when `i == 1`, because one tries to compare `x[1]` to the non-existent `x[0]`. Let's suppose that we never enter the conditional for `i == 1`, so the vectorized version is

```
    tst_2 <- !tst_1 & c(FALSE, tail(x, -1) == head(x, -1)) & z <= q
```

The most straight-forward way to implement the update of `h` is a simple loop like

```
    for (i in which(tst_2))
        h[i] <- h[i - 1] + 1L
```

and finally return the result

```
    h
}
```

The full function, tweaked slightly, is

```
f1 <- function(x, y, z, q) {
    h <- integer(length(x)) # allocate the result inside the function
    ## if (...)
    h[z == y] <- 1L
    ## else if (...)
    tst <- !h & c(FALSE, x[-1] == x[-length(x)]) & z <= q
    for (i in which(tst))
        h[i] <- h[i - 1] + 1L
    h
}
```

Performance can be improved further by focusing on the remaining `for()` loop, but perhaps this already gets you to the performance needed, without being too cryptic?

One could also more cleanly separate the 'filter' operation of selecting relevant events

```
keep <- (y >= z) & (z <= q)
x0 <- x[keep]
```

from the process of operating on each group. Here you're creating a group-wise sequence from 1 to the number of members of the group. Several approaches are

```
h0 <- ave(seq_along(x0), x0, FUN=seq_along)
```

or

```
grp_size = rle(x0)$lengths
offset = rep(cumsum(c(0L, grp_size[-length(grp_size)])), grp_size)
h0 <- seq_len(sum(grp_size)) - offset
```

or

```
grp_size = tabulate(match(x0, unique(x0)))
offset = rep(cumsum(c(0L, grp_size[-length(grp_size)])), grp_size)
h0 <- seq_len(sum(grp_size)) - offset
```

Other solutions to this problem are found elsewhere on StackOverflow.  The final step is to create the return value

```
h <- integer(length(x))
h[keep] <- h0
h
```

`Data` is a tibble, so perhaps you're familiar with dplyr. One way of achieving the result in an intelligible but not necessarily efficient way is

```
d0 <- Data %>%
    filter(
        Activity_Date >= First_Activity_Date, 
        Activity_Date <= Last_Activity_Date
    ) %>% 
    group_by(Customer) %>%
    mutate(Frequency = seq_along(Customer))
left_join(Data, d0)
```

Comment: Thank you Martin on a great answer!! 
It not just solves my problem but it helps me grow as well.
I appreciate it very much!